# Height vs minHeight Toolbar

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity

I recently updated to `AppCompatActivity` and switched from `ActionBar` to `ToolBar`.

When I was checking the xml, I found these two attributes -

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

---

What is the difference between these two attributes? Why is `layout_height` set to `wrap_content` in the ToolBar documentation?

Is it necessary to use both the attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- On using both the attributes, **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`** and **`android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"`**, there is a possibility that your toolbar height may get larger when you use larger icons.
- **`android:minHeight`** ensures that your toolbar will not resize itself smaller than **`?attr/actionBarSize`** value.

If you want your toolbar height to be fixed, just use

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

The other attribute is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok when you specify **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** then your toolbar may  shrink if it's not contain larger child view then the standard actionbar size.

But if you specify **android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"** then it doesn't matter how small view is there in toolbar it will maintain its standard size of ActionBar.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between these two attributes?

`android:minHeight` **Defines the minimum height of the view.** 
`android:layout_height` **Specifies the basic height of the view.** 
Pseudocode for more clear.

```
if(minHeightDefined) {
    if(currentHeightOfView < minHeight) {
        currentHeightOfView = minHeight;
    } else {
        currentHeightOfView = layout_height;
    }
} else {
    currentHeightOfView = layout_height;
}
```

`minHeightDefined` - flag indicate does `android:minHeight` **declared** in layout xml file **or not**

> Why is layout_height set to wrap_content in the ToolBar documentation?

Because [this is](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.java#1687) a default implementation.